# Script IIS 5.1 installation on Windows XP

Tags: windows, scripting, installation, iis-5

I found an idea for [scripting the installation of IIS7 on Vista](http://linrayusa.blogspot.com/2007/09/using-script-to-install-iis-on-windows.html)

I'm looking for a similar solution for IIS 5.1 on Windows XP.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your unattend text file.  Check the following document on the Windows
Server CD for all relevant options:
support\tools\deploy.cab -- unattend.doc on W2K, or ref.chm for XP/W2K3

It looks something like this; here are some common ones you can pick from:

[Components]

iis_common = ON

iis_inetmgr = ON
iis_www = ON

iis_ftp = ON

iis_doc = ON

iis_htmla = ON

iis_pwmgr = ON

mts_core = ON

fp = OFF

fp_extensions = OFF

iis_smtp = OFF

iis_nntp = OFF

2.
Set Registry key at
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\SourcePath = ""
i.e.
SourcePath="\server\share"
where \server\share\i386 contains Windows files.

3.
Run:
SYSOCMGR.EXE /i:sysoc.inf /r /n /u:
Make sure the identity which runs this command has access to \server\share

--